# Question regarding an NAS server and remote users

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage

I have a client that requires a massive amount of storage space but:

1. Doesn't want to spend very much money
2. Needs remote users (across the country) to be able to pull data from it and store to it, as well.

Can this be done with an NAS Server such as the Western Digital Sharespace Network Storage System? I do not believe the client wants to spend over $1400 and HP is offering 8TB for $1299.

Also, if anyone has any other ideas besides using NAS, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the client have any hardware laying around that could be repurposed?

Comment: Does anyone else ever get sick of companies\customers saying " I want a lot of stuff, but I don't want to pay a lot for it"? Why do the principals of economices seem to not apply to the IT world? My boss wants a world class, "never fails" infrastructure, but he doesn't want to pay for redundancy, maintenance and support contracts, etc, etc. It drives me crazy. Sorry for the rant.

Comment: joeqwerty, I completely understand. This happens much too often.

Comment: You say “massive amount of storage,” but don’t say exactly how much. Also does that budget include redundancy and backups?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Nasuni Systems. I don't know what they charge, but generally a NAS gateway into the "cloud" I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The WD Sharespace will allow the remote access you want but you should have a look at what the client is uploading/downlaoding and total number of users.  From WD.. "Access your files anywhere, anytime using MioNet remote access services from WD." 
 It also supports FTP.  We have used a few for local access and they are a solid unit with some nice features.  Buffalo also makes some good units [Buffalo Network Devices](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/)

Comment: Mionet is horrible.  If it is anything like their Mybook World Edition, it might run Linux.  It was CPU-bound on the data-transfer with that product.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/

how about 67 TB for less than $8000 :-)

Comment: $7,867 is slightly more than $1,400 last time I checked.

Comment: sorry, I was using windows calculator.

Answer (score 0):

So, the requirements are 1. Solid product with a lot of features that 2. Costs little to no money?  This sounds like a job for open source!

For the NAS part, take a look at [OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com/).  It's a great application that let's you roll your own NAS/SAN device.  It installs via a bootable CDROM image and is managed via a web GUI, so you don't even need any Linux experience.

To give the remote users secure access to files on Openfiler, set up a firewall that also functions as a VPN endpoint.  My personal preference is a dedicated Linux server running [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/) and [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/).  Shorewall is extremely powerful/flexible but unless you're familiar with managing firewall rulesets in a corporate environment, it has a steep learning curve.  A better solution for a small biz client might be loading [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) onto a [Linksys WRT54GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) and using that in conjunction with the [OpenVPN on DD-WRT instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I greatly appreciate it. The product has been ordered and it is on its way. If I have any questions, I'll be sure to get back to you guys.

Comment: What product is that?